# Submit 2 forms with 1 button, form1 after form 2 is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following problem:

2 forms that need to be submitted with one button. I will explain how it should work.
And of course my code so far.

#frmOne contains a url field where I need to copy the data from to my #frmTwo, this works. 
(it forces the visitor to use www. and not http:// etc)

When I press 1 submit button

> 1. Verify fields #frmOne (only url works now, help needed on the others)
> 2. Call #frmTwo and show result in iframe. result shows progress bar (works)
>      But Div, modal or any other solution besides iframe are welcome.
> 3. Close #frmOne (does not work)
> 4. Finally process (submit) #frmOne if #frmTwo is done  (does not work)

Process completed code of #frmTwo in iframe =

```
<div style='width' id='information'>Process completed</div>

<ol class="forms">
<iframe width="100%" height="50" name="formprogress" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
<div id="txtMessage"></div>
</ol>

<div id="hide-on-submit">
<form id="frmOne" method="post">
<input type="text" name="company" id="company" >
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" >
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" >
<input type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation" >
<textarea rows="20" cols="30" name="summary" id="summary" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>

<form id="frmTwo" method="post" target="formprogress"></form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

    //Cache variables
    var $frmOne             = $('#frmOne'),     
        $frmTwo             = $('#frmTwo'),
        $txtMessage         = $('#txtMessage'),
        frmTwoAction        = 'http://www.mydomainname.com/form.php?url=';

    //Form 1 sumbit event
    $frmOne.on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var strUrl = $frmOne.find('#url').val();

        //validation
        if(strUrl === ''){

            $txtMessage.html('<b>Missing Information: </b> Please enter a URL.'); 
        }        
        else if(strUrl.substring(0,7) === 'http://'){
            //Clear field
            $frmOne.find('#url').val('');            
            $txtMessage.html('<b>http://</b> is not supported!');            
        }
        else if(strUrl.substring(0,4) !== 'www.'){
             //Clear field
            $frmOne.find('#url').val('');            
            $txtMessage.html('<b>Invalid URL</b> Please enter a valid URL!'); 
        }
        else{
           //set form action and submit form
           $frmTwo.attr('action', frmTwoAction +  strUrl).submit();

  $('#hide-on-submit').hide(0).fadeIn(1000);
    $('form#frmOne').submit(function(e) {

        $(this).hide(1000);

            return true; // let form one submit now!
        }   

       return false;

    }); 

});
</script>
```

Comment: I think ajax would help here

Comment: Hello Jonas, okay. But how. (I am not a jquery or ajax professional)

Comment: This is pretty much a textbook version of a cross-frame scripting attack. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting
I would not go down this road. There may be browser security restrictions that will prevent various actions. Find a way to remove the iframes, and have a single form.

Comment: @mastaBlasta both forms are from my own, even the same domain name. one form collects user info the other checks if the server of that person is online. But as mentioned. Bove in the same domain... if you have an better idea, share it with me.

Comment: I would say you're trying to do too much at once. Before getting fancy with ajax, i would do this the old fashioned way: Get the first form, send back to server, validate, do whatever you need to do, if you need to re-display stuff to user then show the page with messages. Then give them the additional options. You should constantly be asking yourself "What am I trying to do?".

Comment: @mastablasta I am already doing that. I am not a beginner, yes on jQuery and java I am, but on design and GUI design I am absolutely not. This is already my second screen. But some data need to be processed separately. So instead of firing some basic lines, show me what you can do. Except talking.

Comment: @mastablasta well if you know ExpressionEngine (CMS) could you combine Cartthrob shop module with Members zoo_visitor module. Is not possible. You need to sync data from Cartthrob to zoo_visitor, and need a screen for that. This gives me problems while I like to keep forms short and on one page...

Answer (score 0):

read here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. basically you need to submit the first one with $.ajax and then, when you get the server response (in the success() function ) you need to send the second form, again width ajax().

Something like:

```
$form1.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //don't send the form yet
    $.ajax(
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize()
    ).success(function(data) {
        alert('form one sent');
        $.ajax(
            url: $('#form2').attr('action'),
            type: $('#form2').attr('method'),
            data: $('#form2').serialize()
        ).success(function(data) {
            alert('form two sent');
        })
    });
});
```

This code isn't ready to be copy/pasted, it's just to give you a guideline of how I would solve it. It's a big question, try going with this solution and come back with smaller question if you find yourself blocked.

Comment: Okay, but form2 should be submitted first. I could copy my code at attr('action')? (I need the visitor given URL to be copied to form2)

Comment: Yes just get that url from the first form and place it as the url parameter in the second ajax call